# Mono.Cecil convert .exe to dll?

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

Is there any way to use Mono.Cecil to convert a exe to a dll, (removing the icon and other unneeded data, removing EntryPoint)

```
    AssemblyDefinition sourceAssembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(file);
    sourceAssembly.EntryPoint = null;
    sourceAssembly.Write(outputFile);
```

does not seem to have any effect at all..

Comment: Isn't renaming the file enough?

Comment: I'm pretty sure @svick's correct. If fact, you don't even have to rename it.... sadly, I've been places where that was done. ;(

Comment: The reason i want to convert it to a dll is that i want to remove all unneeded data to save space!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert a managed .exe to a .dll, you can use:

```
var file = "foo.exe";
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (file);
module.Kind = ModuleKind.Dll;
module.EntryPoint = null;
module.Write (Path.ChangeExtension (file, ".dll"));
```

One thing that isn't implemented yet as of Cecil 0.9.5, is that you can not remove the Win32 icon programmatically. This is bug [#3](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/issues/3).

Fun fact: some .dll of the .net framework do have an entry point.

Comment: Is there any other way to remove the win32 resources from it? or just throw all of them away? in the end im going to save it in a byte array and load it from there, i want to strip as much away as i can!

Comment: @Petoj, not really, not with the current version of Cecil anyway. This will be fixed before Cecil 1.0 though. But I'm not sure this is going to save you a lot a space. Win32 icons are rarely large.

Comment: well every bit counts in my case :P, but sure ill have to wait for 1.0 is there any preliminary release date for this? thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: hmmm found this http://resourcelib.codeplex.com/ haven't tried it yet but it might be able to remove the stuff i don't need :P